# Is there an "interesting" function that grows faster than $n^{kn}$ but slower than $2^{2^n}$ -- relates to understanding googolplex

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function, law-of-large-numbers

Motivation:  I'm looking for some sort of convenient fact I can use to grasp the size of a googolplex.  For a googol we observe a convenient one; it's very nearly equal to 70!.  But for a googolplex I haven't found such an elegant comparison.

One example function I've found that comes close is the "hyperfactorial" defined as:

$$
H(n)
=\prod_{k=1}^n k^k
=1^1\cdot2^2\cdot3^3\cdots(n-1)^{n-1}\cdot n^n.
$$

But this doesn't grow fast enough.  For example H(100) is only on the order of $10^{9014}$ and H(1000) on the order of $10^{1392926}$.

Another idea I had was Perm(n) = the number of permutations of an $n \times n \times n$ Rubick's cube, but again this function doesn't grow fast enough.  Perm(100) is only about $10^{38416}$.

So in the end I would like an "interesting" function whose growth is almost as fast as the doubly exponential $2^{2^n}$ but not as fast.

Comment: I wonder if you could get some insight from Graham's number and the arrow notation?

Comment: Nothing wrong with $f(n)=n^{n^n}$, the number of ways to fill an $n$-dimensional cube of side $n$ with numbers from $1$ to $n$.  You have $f(57)$ roughly a googolplex.

Answer (score 3):

How about a double factorial: (n!)! ?

$(69!)! \approx 10^{1.7 \times 10^{100}}$ is a nice approximation for a googolplex. It also has a relatively straightforward interpretation: Look at the list of all the possible permutations of 69 objects. The number of ways in which you can reorder all the permutations on the list is $(69!)!$.

As for the 7th busy beaver number, it is already known that $BB(7)>10^{10^{10^{10^{18705353}}}}\gg googolplex$. I wonder why you'd want to use busy beavers, anyway, after saying that $2^{2^n}$ grows too fast for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

$n^{kn}=2^{k\,n\log_2(n)}$. Does that help?

---

EDIT: Added later.

This let's us more clearly see that $$n^{kn}=2^{k\,n\log_2(n)}\ll2^{2^n}$$ We can come upon any function between $k\,n\log_2(n)$ and $2^n$ to use in that exponent to find an intermediate function. Like say, $n^2$. Is $2^{n^2}$ "interesting"?

---

Added even later: Imagine an $n\times$ n array of light bulbs that can either be on or off. How many on/off configurations can there be? This gives a possible context to $2^{n^2}$ along the lines of the number of Rubik's permutations as far as "interesting" goes.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea, but it seems somewhat arbitrary.  I'm looking for something that might capture one's imagination.  That makes it easier to teach people.

Comment: @Purplejacket I think might have missed the point of this answer. It rewrites your lower bound so that its base matches your upper bound. Now it is easy to find functions that satisfy your condition. Namely if $kn\log_2(n)<f(x)<2^n$ then $2^{f(x)}$ satisfies what you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, sorry right, didn't look closely at the base (2).  I can come up with facts such as $57^{57^{57}}$ is very close to a googolplex (which is true) but I'm trying to look for a concept other than a double exponential--a contrasting concept.

Comment: A physicist named Don Page claims that the number of states in a black hole with a mass roughly equivalent to the Andromeda Galaxy is in the range of a googolplex, but I'd like a fact something more in the range of pure math.

Comment: I'd love to be able to say "The 7th busy beaver number is very close to a googolplex", but we have no idea about that.

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what you are looking for then. An 'exponential polynomial' like this one sounds to me like an exact parallel to a 'double exponential'. And there's context for it as "the number of ways to do something" similar to counting how many permutations there are for a general Rubik's cube. $\log\log$ of $k^{k^n}$ is linear in $n$; if you want to get "very close" to that, replace "linear" in $n$ with something quite close, like $n^{0.9}$ or $\frac{n}{\log n}$.